# how do I fetch results with mysql for the past six months?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a basic query fetching results for all results earlier than today:

```
...where post_date < '".current_time('mysql')."'....
```

How do I only fetch results for the past 6 months, i.e.:

```
...where post_date > '".current_time('mysql')."' - 6 MONTHS && post_date < '".current_time('mysql')."'...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) (and `GETDATE()`)

```
...where post_date > DATE_SUB(GETDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) ...
```

Comment: how would I use this in my current query?

Comment: sorry took some time to figure that out, i'm used to work with SQL Server :) this should work.

Comment: post_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)

Comment: thanks littlegreen - I guess the below could work too. It seems to me that the majority of the date/time functions are all synonyms of NOW()

Comment: you can use `NOW()`, which returns the current date and time, or `CURDATE()` which returns only the current date, but definitely not `GETDATE()` which works only for SQL Server. -1, but I will remove downvote if/when the answer is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

eg:

```
...  WHERE post_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```